# TItle chapter heading having two lines below it

Tags: chapters

Two lines below chapter heading of different width as shown in image

[image]

This is what I manage to get using code

[image]

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\chapterfont{\centering }
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bf\large\centering}
{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \vspace{1ex}
    \centering
} % before-code
[
\vspace{-0.5ex}%
\rule{\textwidth}{0.3pt}
% after-code
]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a complete code of what you've tried, not a link?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). I tried to "repair" your question. Hopefully I guessed correctly and inserted the images correctly. If my edit does not suit your needs, please feel free to change it.

Comment: \usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\chapterfont{\centering }
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bf\large\centering}
{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \vspace{1ex}
    \centering
} % before-code
[
\vspace{-0.5ex}%
\rule{\textwidth}{0.3pt}
% after-code
]

Comment: In first image two lines below heading are there. How to get those two lines with very small space between them

Comment: How to get two lines below the chapter heading as shown in image 1.

Answer (score 2):

I think the thin line after the thick one would look better. B.t.w., don't load `sectsty` and `titlesec`, to avoid any conflict.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\bfseries\Large\centering}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}{10pt}{%
\MakeUppercase} % before-code
[{\titlerule[1.2pt]\vskip1.2pt\titlerule[0.3pt]}] % after-code

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Bernard thanks a lot for help but I wonder how you all have mastered latex like this. I will not able to master it like this in my whole lifetime. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ leandriis I was struggling with \rule command and adjusting the space using points but not able to get . Actually I have to use \titlerule

Comment: I've been using it for more than 25 years, and I read packages documentations when I feel they might be useful to what I want to do…

Answer (score 1):

Probably the following can serve as a place to start from. Line thicknesses and spacing can of course be adjusted to your needs. I have also added `\MakeUppercase`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\chapterfont{\centering }
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\large\centering}%
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}%
{10pt}%
{\vspace{1ex}\centering\MakeUppercase}%
[{\titlerule[0.5pt]\vspace{1pt}\titlerule[2pt]}]


\begin{document}

\chapter{Design of Experiments}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ leandriis thanks a lot for help but I wonder how you all have mastered latex like this. I will not able to master it like this in my whole lifetime. Thanks a lot